# Delete blank lines in text files

Tags: php

I have a file that turns out to have an empty Righa at the beginning and end of two empty lines wing generating me an error

```
<?php
$file = "https://example.com/text/file.txt";

$fr = fopen($file, 'r');

$contenuto = "";
while (!feof($fr)) {

    $riga = fgets($fr);

    $inizio = strpos($riga, "Capitolo");

    $nuova_riga = substr($riga, $inizio);

    $contenuto .= $nuova_riga . "";
}
fclose($fr);
$fr = fopen("file.txt", 'w');
fwrite($fr, $contenuto);
fclose($fr);
```

Notice: Undefined offset:
Notice: Undefined index:

if you manually delete blank lines obviously I do not have the mistake, so I should open the file for writing suppress blank lines and then continue with the other instructions on the page. How can I do? Thank you

Comment: Where is your code bro?

Answer (score 3):

Not fully understood your question. Maybe so?

```
str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with [file function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) that supports flags.

```
file_put_contents('file.txt',implode('', file('https://example.com/text/file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$resultant=array();
$lines=file("/path/to/your/test.txt");//retrieving lines of the file.

foreach($lines as $value)
{
    if($value!="\n")
    {
        $resultant[]=$value;
    }
}

$string=implode("", $resultant);//combining array into string with null
file_put_contents("/path/wher/you/want/to/save.txt", $string);
```

Comment: In this way not delete blank lines, but add blank lines between a row and the other

Comment: @Michael I have updated my post you can check it will work fine. I have tested it.

Comment: It does not work so the blank lines at the beginning and end remain Looking with notepad ++ see that the rows contain CR and LF is possible to eliminate these

Comment: @Michael can you share a sample of your file?

Comment: The file is created as reported on post